# Perl - Anonymous hashes in arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm trying to add multiple key-value references inside an anonymous array.  This is the code I'm currently using:

```
my %hash;
my $count = 25;
foreach my $var1 ('a'..'e'){
    $hash{'value'} = [
                      'one',
                      'two',
                      {
                            'consensus' => {$var1 => $count},
                            'glimmer'   => {'test' => 'me'},
                      }
                    ];
    $count -= 5;
    print "INITIAL-$var1: ", $hash{'value'}->[2]{'consensus'}{$var1}, "\n";
}

foreach my $var1 ('a'..'e'){
    print "FINAL-$var1: ", $hash{'value'}->[2]{'consensus'}{$var1}, "\n";
}

print Dumper(%hash);
```

However, what happens is that every time $var1 and $count change, it overwrites the previous instance of $var1 => $count.  I was wondering if there is a way to add new key-value pairs to this data structure (rather than declaring it at the start through

`$hash{'value'}{'consensus'} = ...`

Edit: Sorry about that, right now I get:

```
$VAR2 = [
          'one',
          'two',
          {
            'glimmer' => {
                           'test' => 'me'
                         },
            'consensus' => {
                             'e' => 5
                           }
          }
        ];
```

However, I'm looking to make:

```
$VAR2 = [
          'one',
          'two',
          {
            'glimmer' => {
                           'test' => 'me'
                         },
            'consensus' => {
                             'a' => 25
                             'b' => 20
                             'c' => 15
                             'd' => 10
                             'e' => 5
                           }
          }
        ];
```

Comment: well, what is the data structure you actually want at the end? It's much easier to show you the way when we know where you're going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OR simply:

```
$count = 25;
$x = 5;
$hash{'value'} = [
                  'one',
                  'two',
                  {
                        'consensus' => {map {$_, $count - (5*$x--)} ('a' .. 'e')},
                        'glimmer'   => {'test' => 'me'},
                  }
                ];
```

Answer (score 1):

The parts you only want to do once should not be in the loop!

There's one array in your desired results, yet you create five in your code. The array creation should not be within the loop.

There's one hash in the array in your desired results, yet you create five in your code. The hash creation should not be within the loop.

There are two third-level hashes in your desired results, yet you create ten in your code. The hash creation should not be within the loop.

```
my %hash = (
    value => [
        'one',
        'two',
        {
            'consensus' => { },
            'glimmer'   => { test => 'me' },
        },
    ],
);

my $count = 25;
for my $i ('a'..'e') {
    $hash{value}[2]{consensus}{$i} = $count;
    $count -= 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
push @{$hash{'value'}}, 'one', 'two'
foreach my $var1 ('a'..'e'){
    push @{$hash{'value'}}, {'consensus' => {$var1 => $count}};
    $count -= 5;
    print "INITIAL-$var1: ", $hash{'value'}->[2]{'consensus'}{$var1}, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning a new anonymous array ref each time, which overwrites the old one:

```
$hash{'value'} = [ .... # old value is overwritten
```

What you need is to simply use assignment directly to the hash key/values.

```
$hash{'value'}->[2]{'consensus'}{$var1} = $count;
```

You can also generate the hash ref and assign it directly, e.g.:

```
my $href;
for my $letter ('a'..'e') {
    $href->{$letter} = $count;
    $count -= 5;
}
$hash{'value'}->[2]{'consensus'} = $href;
```